# Switching between windows with cmd-tab

Tags: snow-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best app to switch between all open windows (Witch alternatives)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows-witch-alternatives)

In Microsoft Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combination switches between all windows from all applications. In Mac, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> only switches between applications, and when you want to switch between windows in single application, you have to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. I'm used to Windows behavior and I like it more. Is it possible to configure <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between all windows from all applications?

Comment: It is partial duplicate, but if there is any way to achieve this in plain Mac OS, I would be 100% happy :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do it, but Exposé ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expos%C3%A9_%28Mac_OS_X%29)) is pretty good.

Alternatively there are some third-party apps which are might help.