# How to change Cmd+Tab on OS X to make it behave like on Windows or Linux?

Tags: window-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best app to switch between all open windows (Witch alternatives)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows-witch-alternatives)

I'm looking for a way of making the window switching behave more like on Windows, to switch to last open Window instead of switching to the next.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to buy another app. Two I know of are

[Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/)
[Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/)

Or get used to Apple's way which is use Exposé