# Is there a way to split the Cmd-Tab app list onto multiple rows?

Tags: macos, application-switcher

Is there an app/program for OS X that will "split" the list of open apps that appears when you hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> into multiple rows?

This is the default behaviour for Windows 7 and it's really quite useful when you have lots of windows open, navigating with the arrow keys.

Comment: Related to [How to change cmdtab on os x to make it behave like on windows or linux](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10502/how-to-change-cmdtab-on-os-x-to-make-it-behave-like-on-windows-or-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/)? It may not be 100% what you're after, but I find it nicer than the built-in application switching.

[image]

Comment: Nice, thats awesome! Works perfectly.