# Keyboard shortcut for switching between open windows

Tags: keyboard, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best app to switch between all open windows (alternatives to Witch)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows-alternatives-to-witch)

On Windows and Linux one can switch between open windows by pressing Alt+Tab. On the Mac pressing Cmd+Tab only lets one switch between windows of different applications. In order to switch between windows of the same application one has to press Cmd+` instead. 
Is it possible to disable that behavior, and use Cmd+Tab to switch between all windows regardless of whether they belong to the same application?

Answer (score 5):

[Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) is the way to go. I used it everyday for many years and it never let me down. The support is great and reactive. In addition, it has many option, so you can configure it to your desires and then forget it isn't part of OS X.