# How can I use command+tab to switch between windows of the same app in addition to all the other apps?

Tags: switching, unix, application-switcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best app to switch between all open windows (alternatives to Witch)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows-alternatives-to-witch)

I would like to see all the windows, including from the same app, when I switch between them (command+tab). See an example from Ubuntu (image attached).

I know this may raise an issue of distinguishing between the same app windows. For that, there is a solution - a preview and the title of the window - see Ubuntu's static switcher (image attached).

I know the preview feature (F3 or fn+F3) but I can't continue choosing the right app using the keyboard and it's way slower than command+tab.

Thanks.

[image: Ubuntu's static app switcher]

Comment: Whoever down votes the question, please explain, so the question could be improved. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I'm new to mac and trying to adapt to it (relatively successfully) but the app switching is killing me.

Comment: I did not downvote the question, but if I were to make a guess, I think it is because of its style *"How can I make OSX behave like Ubuntu?"*.

Comment: @gentmatt - Ubuntu is just an example, because I know it. All I want is to switch between all the windows at the same time and just applications.

Comment: Why not just use Cmd + ` (Command tilde)? That's just above tab and works perfectly.

Comment: @bassplayer7, right, it works, but not as I'd like to. If I have a task with 2 chrome Windows and a terminal, its hard to switch between the three. Especially if there are other chrome Windows that are part of another task.

Answer (score 8):

What you are trying to achieve is not provided by OS X and I don't know if a third-party application would be able to interfere this deeply in the window management.

You have two options:

1. (<kbd>⇧</kbd> +) <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to switch between apps
2. (<kbd>⇧</kbd> +) <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to switch between windows of one app in one desktop

Option two is configurable in *System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard & Text Input → Move focus to next Window*.

You can still achieve something similar to what you have in Ubuntu by using [Mission Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Control_%28OS_X%29) and **not** choosing the option **Group windows by applications** in:
 *System Preferences → Mission Control → Group windows by applications*

Then define a gesture to use initiate Mission Control for all individual Windows in: 
*System Preferences → Trackpad → More Gestures → Mission Control*

Note that there is also an option for *App Exposé* which is like Mission Control for just one application.

Comment: I don't understand how will this offer me an option to switch between the windows (using the keyboard) and not just between the apps. Also, I don't see the grouping option in the Preferences.

Comment: @kilaka The answer merely says that Mission Control offers something similar and suggests using the multi-touch trackpad for navigation. The grouping option is only available in Mountain Lion (OSX 10.8). You can also use keys to initiate Mission Control in *System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcut -> Mission Control -> Mission Control*

Comment: It is possible to use the up/down arrow keys to toggle between multiple windows of the same app while you are Cmd + Tabbing through your open applications.