# Gris virtual desktops on OSX lion

Tags: macos

having to work on a mac and used to Linux like virtual desktops I quickly activated surfaces to get my usual workspace on. Thing is, I recently had to upgrade to OSX lion in order to get XCode and Lion seems to have removed the possibility to create a 3X3 layer of virtual desktop.

Obviously I unsuccessfully googled my problem without finding anything except some people complaining about this removal and so paying software offering a different virtual desktop solution.

Is there any free virtual desktop software that I could use on OSX lion or any settings that will revert the virtual desktop to the way they were before ?

I'm looking for something that allows me to go from one VD to another with Ctrl + arrow ( up down left right ) and Ctrl + numpad. Huge bonus if someone has a solution that get rid of the absurd Alt+Tab mechanism OSX provide.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For alt tab see [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows-alternatives-to-witch) and have you tried the OSX virtual desktop in Mission COntrol?

Comment: I did try MissionControl, but it only offers virtual desktop in a line shape which kinda ruin my habit of having my IDE in the center of my grid and everything else around one shortcut away. 
Thanks for the link, I'll try this tomorrow.