# Alt-Tabbing through windows

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut, application-switcher

I'm used to having <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> set to cycle forward through the windows of a single app and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go backwards. I had this working on Yosemite by fiddling with the shortcuts in **System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts**.

But after upgrading to El Capitan, it is only Finder that responds to these commands, no other Apps, although they have not assigned this shortcut for something else.

Is there a way to enable this behaviour on El Capitan for all apps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best app to switch between all open windows](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these third-party solutions are what I'm looking for. On Yosemite one could make do without them.

Comment: By default - alt and tab shifts the keyboard focus within the frontmost window - the one with focus for the keyboard. It has nothing to do with app switching. Command + Tab switches between apps that run. Can you make a new user account and re-verify that you haven't made some custom changes to keyboard shortcuts? It sounds like that's the case since what you report doesn't match how the OS comes out of the box at 10.11.

Comment: @bmike I realized that now it works with Finder as expected (not sure what changed), but other apps do not respond to alt-tab at all, although I can't see that they have somehow overridden it. This is a fresh install, so no changes to the user account have been made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your problem. The functionality is there and works as expected. Go to **System Preferences / Keyboard / Shortcuts / Keyboard** and choose whatever key combination you want for switching windows in *Move focus to next window* setting, say <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. This will switch application windows forward and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will switch application windows in reverse order, which is exactly what you wanted. The reverse order functionality is already implied by the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and you don't need to set it separately. Mind you that if you choose combination that already includes the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key for forward order it will not imply the shortcut for reverse order without the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

Comment: There is nothing to move to the ***previous*** window.

Comment: A move to previous window is whatever you set as a shortcut to next window+Shift key.

Comment: Well you are correct w r t Finder, but it does not seem to work with all apps anymore, e.g. Safari or Chrome.

Comment: I can confirm that it fully works with Safari 9.1.1, Chrome 51.0.2704.106, TextEdit, Preview, Pages, Numbers, Keynote and others on OS X El Capitan 10.11.5. I'm guessing that it will work for any Mac OS X application that follows recommended Apple Mac App [design guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543). That being said, apps that feature full screen mode and tabbed windows exhibit different behaviours.

Comment: It must have been some other problem that caused this functionality to break for me. Unfortunately I do not remember what I did to fix it.

Comment: It doesn't do anything in my case. The default shortcut is command + ` but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ChristianVielma Just checked with macOS 10.13.3 and Safari 11.0.3 and it works as described.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution.

First I remap keys like this to simulate the Windows <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcuts:

[image]

---

and then I use [HyperSwitch](http://hyperswitch.bahoom.com/) like this

[image]

Comment: How do you get to the first screen to re-map?