# How can I reprogram OSX to use Windows-style shortcuts for all operations?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've recently started using a Mac after using Windows for 20+ years and one annoying thing is that I have to re-learn all the shortcuts. I've found that you can change small stuff like swapping the Ctrl, Fn and Option buttons, but the shortcuts themselves would still be different from what I am used to. I've also found Karabiner helpful for remapping individual keys, but it won't let me create more complex rules, such as assigning Alt-Tab to change between Windows.

Is there a program/extension/terminal command that would allow me to remap any shortcut in the system to any other shortcut combination?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118085/discussion-on-question-by-jonathanreez-how-can-i-reprogram-osx-to-use-windows-st).

Comment: Somewhat related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The answer to my question is to use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) along with their set of complex key modifications titled "[PC-Style Shortcuts](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#pc_shortcuts)". You can also add modifications of your own by editing the `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json` file.

The only shortcut I couldn't get working is using `Alt+Shift` to switch between input languages, but it's probably doable using more advanced scripting. I'm instead using Macs built-in language toggling using the `Caps lock` key. Top this off with [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/) to enable Windows-style toggling between applications/windows and you get a full PC experience, completely customizable to your personal needs.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but thank you, this does exactly what I was looking for.  I switch back and forth between Windows and Mac a lot and it gets confusing having to remap the commands in my mind back and forth all day long.  Now I just need to find out how to change the alt+tab behavior to match Windows.

Comment: Using this one: https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=%20PC-Style%20Shortcuts . It works for certain applications (like Microsoft Outlook), but I can't get it to work for the `Finder` (for example, I can't do `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V` to copy+paste, I'm still stuck with the Mac shortcuts). Any clues?

Comment: @payne weird, it does work for me in Finder. I'm on Catalina.

Comment: This saved my sanity, thank you! For a tutorial on creating your own complex modifications on Karabiner: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBPS2D9AKtI

Comment: @user3062913 For alt-tab shortcut, the AltTab application does the job for me: https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/

Comment: Just a heads up, there's a few with the name "PC-Style Shortcuts" but this one worked best for me: https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#pc_shortcuts

Comment: Karabiner is exactly what I need, except it doesn't work with Synergy... :-(

Answer (score 2):

I agree with all the comments so far, your better off learning the Mac shortcuts. That being said, you can change a lot of shortcuts using the keyboard preferences:

Apple Menu > System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts

Most of the finder an system shortcuts are in there. You can then create your own ones by selecting "App Shortcuts", click the + button, select the app you want to modify, enter the menu title and a shortcut. This happen live with the application open. Have a dig around, you'd be surprised how many tasks can be changed.

Remember also that the Mac uses gestures a lot. Sometime they are faster than keyboard shortcuts if you have a touchpad.

Apple Menu > System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard
Click the "Modifier Keys" button bottom right and swap the Alt/Option key and the Command key if needed.

You could also try [Witch by ManyTricks](https://manytricks.com/witch/)

Comment: How would learning Mac shortcuts improve the efficiency of my work assuming I could just reprogram the system to use my old ones? I don't really understand that part...

Comment: @JonathanReez  I suppose most feel that the reprogramming can be so tedious that it is not worth the trouble, but you are certainly the best judge of that.  If you try it, add something later to your question to indicate the results and any problems you ran into.

Comment: "I agree with all the comments so far, your better off learning the Mac shortcuts.", emm. No.

Answer (score 1):

Changing shortcuts from one key to another is one thing, but some functions are inherently different -- like the way that <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles between *applications*, not windows.

There is no built-in functionality to cycle between all windows that you can assign to a key command. You may be able to find third-party software that will provide such functions, of course.

Ultimately: "different platform is different", and there's only so much that can be done to mirror the familiar environment.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer to include a mention of [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/). It lets you configure Command-Tab to work Windows-style or in any other way you personally prefer. No need to adapt yourself or learn anything new if you don't want to, its the *system* that should adapt for your personal needs :)

Comment: Another example: moving files around. In File Explorer, you *Cut* the file from where it is, then *Paste* it where you want to move it. Cut works differently on macOS; if you cut something it vanishes immediately, and if you don't paste it... it's just gone. To prevent accidentally losing files this way, macOS does it differently: you *Copy* the file from where it is, then *Option-Paste* it where you want to move it. And another: closing windows doesn't always quit programs on macOS; you need to quit the app, not just close its window.

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes, I hate that about macOS and sadly there isn't a good third party plugin to fix this. But a lot of stuff can indeed be fixed instead of being forced to adapt.