# How to use same keyboard shortcuts across windows and mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard, windows, shortcut, keybindings

I use both Windows and Mac OS for my work. Unfortunately the keyboard shortcuts across the two are different. For example, on Windows I have to use Ctrl + C to copy whereas on Mac the shortcut is Cmd + C. I am wondering if anyone has succeeded in using the same set of shortcuts from Windows on the Mac?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312656/how-can-i-reprogram-osx-to-use-windows-style-shortcuts-for-all-operations

Comment: I’m going to edit this to be how to make Mac like windows. The inverse question would be off topic here but on topic at Super User I would presume. If you can let us know how your question is different than the [linked ones](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/299361/) with an edit - we might have more specific advice than the questions covering this already here.

Comment: Ctrl+C does the same as Cmnd+C on my personal mac and the IMacs in the computer lab. So you can use Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V on both no issue.

Comment: @SolarMike In which applications did you try this?

Comment: @nohillside happened to be in Excel at the time...