# Excluding Emacs from Karabiner

Tags: keyboard, karabiner

So to ease my transition into the MacOS realm, I found and installed this amazing tool called [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/), importing specifically the rules named [Windows shortcuts on macOS](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#windows_shortcuts_on_macos), as they seem the closest to my 40 YO finger habits.

It works great, except for when I am within Emacs. How do I exclude Emacs from my currently running Karabiner rules?

Comment: "Excluding" Emacs from Karabiner? [You just discovered the huge downside to trying to make a Mac act like a Windows box](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/378477/119271).  [You should modify an application specific binding](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/463604/119271)

Comment: @Allan Your first link points to "Why emacs commands work everywhere on macOS?" If this was intended, the OP might benefit from a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @Allan I am looking for [Karabiner-specific](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312864/504710) instructions.

Comment: Emacs isn't an "add-in" on macOS, it's deep in the DNA.  My advice is to get used to the differences and work from there.

Comment: @allan The OP wants to disable Karabiner while within Emacs, they don't want to disable the emacs-like Cocoa keybindings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To exclude Emacs from Karabiner, simply add the Emacs bundle identifier to each `frontmost_application_unless` clause in `karabiner.json`.

The bundle identifier of Emacs is `org.gnu.Emacs` and in `karabiner.json` insert into each rule's conditions section like this:

```
"conditions": [
    {
        "bundle_identifiers": [
            "^org\\.gnu\\.Emacs$"
        ],
        "type": "frontmost_application_unless"
    }
],
```

Once you do that, open the `Kabiner-Elements` app, click `Quit, Restart` at the bottom of the left pane, then (under `Action`), click the `Restart Karabiner-Elements` button.

Comment: Thanks. Works great.