# Switch windows of an application across desktops

Tags: macos, mission-control, application-switcher

Is there a way (which does not cost a buck) to switch between windows **across desktops** with **<kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>?** Not between apps, but between windows.

Meaning: if I have a Chrome window on desktop 1 and another on desktop 2, just by <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>'ing, I could switch across both.

Comment: This is not a duplicate at all. The accepted answer specifically states: "This only works if all windows are in the same Space". I don't want to click or use two different shortcuts, I just need to switch through all windows in all the spaces using alt+tab. There might not be any solution, but this is different that stating this has been answered already.

Comment: Is there one that you know of that's a paid app?

Comment: I don't know any app that satisfies those requirements. [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/270770/292173) proposes multiple apps, but the free one do not do what I am looking for.

Comment: Um.... https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127414/263848

Comment: I just noticed this too.... kinda lame. Maybe worth sending a feature requires to apple. Anyways there is a native workaround. If you go to `System Prefs -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Mission Control`, there you'll see `Move to Desktop X` and a shortcut for it. Enable them. Use them when you wanna switch to a window on a different desktop. As long as there is a windows on that Desktop it'll switch to the same app.

Comment: @JBis HyperSwitch does not allow you to switch to every window just using Option+Tab. You still have to do some finger gymnastics to get to your window. But, it seems to be the least worst solution so far...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know a keyboard shortcut for that.

But using the mouse or trackpad, just click of the already active application icon in the dock. If that application has windows in various desktops, each click will cycle to the next desktop having some windows of that application.

Comment: That works, yes, but it's also unbearably cumbersome to switch between keyboard and mouse, which is why I'm keyboard shortcuts in the first place!

Comment: @Chris I agree. If you find out a keyboard shorcut I would be more than happy to hear about it ! In the meantime, I use that as I don't know any better way...