# How to make each monitor act as a separate desktop instead of all changing together?

Tags: macos, display

So I have my laptop hooked up with two external monitors. Let's say I have a browser, code editor, and terminal open in each screen. If on my laptop I change from my code editor to the browser, it changes all screens to the browser. The behavior I want, is for it to change the app only on the current screen, and leave the other two screens as they were. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of [#339884](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339884). There is no native support for this (other than the non-keyboard workaround of using Mission Control or clicking a specific window), but third-party solutions are available; see that question for examples. In macOS, when a you switch from one application to another, *all* of its windows are brought to the front of the window stack, not just the most recent one, nor just the ones that exist on the monitor which you were using when you switched to that application.

Comment: @JivanPal If you believe it is a duplicate you should mark it to close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent macOS from bringing all windows to front when switching to an app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339884/prevent-macos-from-bringing-all-windows-to-front-when-switching-to-an-app)