# Show window preview when switching windows of the SAME app

Tags: keyboard, window-manager, application-switcher

I've recently switched to MacOS from Ubuntu, and have been trying to replicate my usual keyboard shortcuts for window management.  I'm using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to switch between windows of the same app, but when doing so, I can't see which window I'm switching to until I've already made the switch!

In Ubuntu, it works a bit differently:  it shows a preview of all open windows for the current application.  See below:
[image: Ubuntu app switcher]

Note the preview of each Terminal window.  This allows me to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> around until I find the window I'm looking for.

Is there any way to add this functionality to macOS?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows for a more Windows like window switcher (Ubuntu copies Windows here)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F11</kbd>  will show all current application windows. left/right arrows will step through them. Enter will select.

This is a subset of [Shortcut for toggling between different windows of same app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app) which you can invoke similarly from the  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   app switcher, except in that case you use the down arrow to switch you into this mode.

If you'd find  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>↓</kbd>   better all round, you can change that in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control - though you can't do the inverse & make both  <kbd>F11</kbd>

If your habit is to always go right for  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   every time, then you can quickly do left, down to flip through windows in the *existing* app.
You call as to which you might prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd> + <kbd>Mission Control/F3</kbd> to switch between windows of the same app.

Alternatively, press <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Mission Control/F3</kbd> to open Mission Control in System Preferences. Make note of what's under "Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts":
[image]
To switch between application windows of the same app, the default keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

After pressing <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>, you should be able to see all open windows of the current app, and switch to one by either point-clicking or by using the arrow keys and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note that this doesn't work when an app is in full screen.

An aside: <kbd>F11</kbd> (Usually <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> if your function keys have default behaviour) shows desktop, by default. <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Mission Control/F3</kbd> does the same thing.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by this - though admittedly it's been many years since I saw the default key commands for any of this. I think many of the key commands you're talking about are the 'special function' keys, not the actual F-keys, so this is going to be dependant on whether you use them as defaults. Show desktop on F11 is the true F-key, so you'd need to add Fn to have it work the same as your other commands. [This is one reason I never use the special function keys;)

Comment: Edited my answer to refer to the Mission Control key as Mission Control key