# OSX cmd+tab behavior with multiple windows of same application and monitors

Tags: display, safari

*First of all, my question is not answered in any of the questions with the similar titles. My context is a little different.*

I have 2 monitors connected to my MacBook Pro. I opened 2 windows of Safari, one for each monitor.

- On 1st monitor, there's a Safari window and Application A.
- On 2nd monitor, there's the 2nd Safari window and Application B.
- 2nd monitor is focused on Application B.
- 1st monitor is focused on Application A.
- On the 1st monitor, I switch from Application A to Safari using `cmd+tab` and 1st monitor successfully focuses on it's own Safari window.
- But 2nd monitor also switches to it's own Safari windows instead of keeping the Application B on the screen.

How can I prevent this from happening so 2nd monitor doesn't switch to Safari as well and instead keep it's application on its screen?

I already tried all the combinations from Mission Control page but none of them helped me achieve this. Or maybe they didn't work as they intended to be, I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: Please add links to these other questions and explain why yours is different. Also, what do you mean with "Mission Control page" and what exactly have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to ignore the Apple paradigm is to use one of the suggestions in [Best app to switch between all open windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows)

These basically make <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> behave as  <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> does in Microsoft Windows, that is the keypress switches between windows independent of which app they are from only bringing one window to the front.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to fight the basic paradigm. Bringing an app to the front… brings it all to the front, no matter which screen it's on.

The simplest workaround I could think of would be to use a different browser app on each screen.