# Make Microsoft Teams Focus on the Proper Window

Tags: ms-office

Is there a way to make ⌘-tab switching to Microsoft Teams actually focus on the app? There's a hidden/ invisible window called "Microsoft Teams Notification" that is always the default selection when I tab back, which means the actual app I want to use is still buried under other stuff. Ideally I would be able to swap to the right window *and* be brought into the chat box, but at this point I will settle for just the first part.

I've tried writing Apple Script to force the issue, but it looks like Teams does not provide hooks for Apple Script.

[image: Phony window]

Comment: Note quite the answer but solving the general case to switch between windows not apps would work as from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been an issue forever. Microsoft doesn’t care.

A potential workaround that sometimes solves the problem is the ability to replace the silly tiny badly-programmed Chrome window notifications that should never have existed with real macOS notifications.

Native notification functionality is in the [developer preview of Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-intro) and can be enabled from notification settings. It’s been in development for 5 years and only available in developer preview for 1.5 years, so don’t hold much hope for it coming to the normal build soon.

Also, I say only sometimes because there’s still lots of cases where the main Teams window doesn’t activate even when it’s the only window in the list of windows, such as if it’s in a full screen space on a secondary display. There’s no workaround for this — again Microsoft need to fix this.

Comment: Your answer inspired me to pursue the preview thing again. Someone finally found the right setting and now I have a single window version of Teams. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. Sort of: it works as expected until I get a notification (when not focused on the app) -- then it goes back to having a second window for notifications. Sigh.