# Change keyboard shortcut for switching applications on macOS Big Sur

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, shortcuts-app, karabiner

I am a Windows user, and I'd like all my shortcuts to work like Windows shortcuts. I've setup Karabiner, and got 99% of the way there. But one thing is missing: I want alt-tab/alt-tab-shift (in Windows keyboard terms) to bring up the App Switcher. I do *not* want to change the location of my modifier keys, because, as I said, Karabiner has been setup to help me there.

Karabiner can map the keyboard shortcut for the App Switcher, [but it has an annoying bug that if you move the mouse whatsoever, it interrupts the keyboard input and selects whatever the App Switcher happens to be over at the time](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/2304).

I want an app/trick to switch the keys for the App Switcher, but *only* the App Switcher. Ideally, this would be a free solution, but if only a paid version exists, I'd be willing to purchase it.

I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.4.

Comment: A lot of apps are mentioned in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows but Witch is the one that I have used for many years for alt-tab to work like MS Windows

Comment: Alt-Tab looks like on Windows, but treats different tabs of windows as different windows - depending on the application.